# Nagios: Make sure x out of y services are running

Tags: monitoring, nagios, high-availability

I'm introducing 24/7 monitoring for our systems. To avoid unnecessary pages in the middle of the night I want Nagios to NOT page me, if only one or two of the service checks fail, as this won't have any impact on users: The other servers run the same service and the impact on users is almost zero, so fixing the problem has time until the next day.

But: I want to get paged if too many of the checks fail.

For example: 50 servers run the same service, 2 fail -> I can still sleep.
The service fails on 15 servers -> I get paged because the impact is getting to high.

What I could do is add a lot (!) of notification dependencies that only trigger if numerous hosts are down. The problem: Even though I can specify to get paged if 15 hosts are down, I still have to define exactly which hosts need to be down for this alert to be sent. I rather want to specify that if *ANY* 15 hosts are down a page is made.

I'd be glad if somebody could help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm using Shinken which has [business rules](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/features/business-rules/) just for that. Shinken is backward compatible with Nagios, so it's easy to drop your nagios configuration into shinken.

It seems there is a similar addon for nagios [Nagios Business Process Intelligence Addon](http://library.nagios.com/library/products/nagiosxi/documentation/329-using-bpi), but I'm not having experience with this addon.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for sharing your experience. I can't just move everything to Shrinken and Nagios the Nagios Business Process Intelligence Addon seems not really nice to use. I decided to just write a simple python script, that will solve everything I need and take a third of the time. I'll share my insights on this later here.